# React Native: _this.setState is not a function being thrown in react-navigation app

Tags: react-native

I have a React app working in expo snack but need to add navigation. When I do, I am getting _this.setState is not a function. Any help is greatly appreciated as this is fairly new to me. Without the navigation in place and utilizing  export default class App extends Component, the app builds and runs as it should but I ma having trouble figuring out where/how to declare setState.

Here's the code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { View, ActivityIndicator, Text,SafeAreaView,FlatList,ImageBackground,Image,StyleSheet,TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import MapView, { Marker } from "react-native-maps";
import axios from 'axios';
const GOOGLE_MAPS_APIKEY = "xxxxxxxx";



function HomeScreen() {
   
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const state  = { reports: [] }



const mapMarkers = () =>  {
    return state.reports.map((report) => <Marker
      key={report.anum}
      coordinate={{ latitude: report.lat, longitude: report.lon }}
      title={report.name}
      description={report.image}
    >
    </Marker >)
  }
 
const getMovies = async () => {
     fetch('https://xxxxx.cfm?d3d2fcs1d')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({reports: data.reports}, () =>  {
        console.log(data)
        }
        
      )})
      .catch(console.error)
                       
  }


getMovies()

 return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
     
       <MapView
        style={{ ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject }}
        initialRegion={{
          latitude: 34.8527370,
          longitude: -82.3933179,
          latitudeDelta: .01,
          longitudeDelta: .01
        }}  apikey={GOOGLE_MAPS_APIKEY} >
        {mapMarkers()}
      </MapView>
        </View>
  );
   
}

function DetailsScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Details Screen</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} options={{headerShown: false}}/>
        <Stack.Screen name="Details" component={DetailsScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  MainContainer: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: 50,
 backgroundColor: '#000',
  },
  logo: {
    width: '90%',
    height: 159,
    marginTop: 4,
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  bannerAd: {
    width: '100%',
    height: 80,
    marginBottom: 12,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#000',
  },
  imageThumbnail: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    height: 100,
  },
});

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see that maybe you confused React Functional Components and React Class Components. If you decide to declare your React component a function then you can use React Hooks like `useState`. But if you rather choose Class components, then you can use `this.state` or `this.setState` because there are no React Hooks

**To fix these mismatches, your code should look like this instead:**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import {
    View,
    ActivityIndicator,
    Text,
    SafeAreaView,
    FlatList,
    ImageBackground,
    Image,
    StyleSheet,
    TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import MapView, { Marker } from 'react-native-maps';
import axios from 'axios';
const GOOGLE_MAPS_APIKEY = 'xxxxxxxx';

function HomeScreen() {
    const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    // EDIT 1:  Add react state hook to manage reports
    const [reports, setReports] = useState([]);
    
    // EDIT 3: only fetch movies once the screen loaded and not every time it renders
     useEffect(() => {

        // EDIT 4: run getMovies() asynchronously
        (async () => { 
              await getMovies(); 
        })(); 
     }, []);

    const mapMarkers = () => {
        return reports.map((report) => (
            <Marker
                key={report.anum}
                coordinate={{ latitude: report.lat, longitude: report.lon }}
                title={report.name}
                description={report.image}
            ></Marker>
        ));
    };

    const getMovies = async () => {
        fetch('https://xxxxx.cfm?d3d2fcs1d')
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((data) => {
                //  EDIT 2: Update reports state
                setReports(data.reports, () => {
                    console.log(data);
                });
            })
            .catch(console.error);
    };

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <MapView
                style={{ ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject }}
                initialRegion={{
                    latitude: 34.852737,
                    longitude: -82.3933179,
                    latitudeDelta: 0.01,
                    longitudeDelta: 0.01,
                }}
                apikey={GOOGLE_MAPS_APIKEY}
            >
                {mapMarkers()}
            </MapView>
        </View>
    );
}

function DetailsScreen() {
    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
            <Text>Details Screen</Text>
        </View>
    );
}

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function App() {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
                <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
                <Stack.Screen name="Details" component={DetailsScreen} />
            </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    MainContainer: {
        justifyContent: 'center',
        flex: 1,
        paddingTop: 50,
        backgroundColor: '#000',
    },
    logo: {
        width: '90%',
        height: 159,
        marginTop: 4,
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    bannerAd: {
        width: '100%',
        height: 80,
        marginBottom: 12,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#000',
    },
    imageThumbnail: {
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        height: 100,
    },
});

export default App;
```

**EDIT 1:** and **EDIT 2:** should do the trick.

Now to avoid a loop when your screen loads, it is always recommend not to update the state in the main render function. So I added **EDIT 3:** to fix that as well.

Furthermore have a look at React Hooks: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Comment: Thank you both so much for the help! When I run Franz's code, the data doesn't appear to load into the app.

Comment: @ChrisBizzell checkout the new edit (EDIT 4) it should now work!

Answer (score 0):

You have a functional component so should not use setState.

You have already a hook to store your data, you should update that setData and where you are trying to use state now, use the data from that hook instead. (const [data, setData] = useState([]);)
Another thing, the way you have getMovies() called it will happen on each render.
Generally for async data fetching you want to use a useEffect hook.
You would want this to happen on mount, and you should also cleanup in case the component becomes unmounted before the call finished.

```
      useEffect(() => {
    let controller = new AbortController();
    (async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch('https://xxxxx.cfm?d3d2fcs1d', {
          signal: controller.signal
        });
        const data = response.json();
        setData(data.reports);

        controller = null;
      } catch (e) { 
        // Handle fetch error
      }
    })();
    return () => controller?.abort();
  }, []);
```